# opnet and matlab interfacing

Tags: matlab, opnet

Can anyone help me in the interfacing of opnet with matlab
I have a gain value returned from the matlab and this value must be set to OPC_TDA_RA_RX_GAIN by using 
op_td_set_dbl (pkptr, OPC_TDA_RA_RX_GAIN, gain);
the problem that there is no difference in the network performance after this value has been added any suggestion for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The TDA value only set in the **pipeline stage**. Otherwise, the new value is not set in `OPC_TDA_RA_RX_GAIN` field.

Check where do u use the `op_td_set_dbl()` function move it to one of pipeline state. The best one would be 'receiver antenna gain` stage.

Thanks.

Comment: I'll  use it in the receiver antenna gain (dra_ragain) to modify the gain value.